# Angular filter does not work for specific keyword. Why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am facing one strange issue. I have added search field on my page which filters record from the table. It works absolutely fine **EXCEPT** `it does not work on 'User' keyword.`

**e.g.** If enter search criteria as '`User`' in text field than it doesn't filter records having 'User' word in it. It works perfect for every other keyword.

Here is my code.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchUser" placeholder="Enter search criteria.">

<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users | filter: searchUser">
        <td>{{user.FirstName}} {{user.LastName}} <small>({{user.RoleName}})</small></td>
        <td ng-repeat="permission in user.Permissions">
            <input ng-disabled="!permission.Enable" type="checkbox">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Whats wrong with keyword `'User'?`

Following is the way i am populating $scope.users

```
$scope.users.push({
    FirstName: user.User.FirstName,
    LastName: user.User.LastName,
    Role: userRole.Name,
    Permissions: angular.copy(permissions),
```

Comment: maybe you should add the "true" comparator for strict comparison: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter  ``filter:searchUser:true``

Comment: @ Betty St, it makes sense and it works for 'User' keyword... However one doubt with 'true' it also accept 'backspace' key and perform search on it. How i can stop system to accept 'backspace'?

Comment: what do you mean? prevent search when typing backspace?

Comment: Works Fine: http://plnkr.co/edit/sN3reYytR3sCKmhzB5Lt?p=preview, unless of course you're including the apostrophes around the word User, but why would you do that?

Comment: @ Betty St, yes i want to prevent search when typing backspace becuase now with true it takes backspace as character and execute search

Comment: @ KreepN, i rechecked my data there is no apostrophes around it.

Comment: So, quick clarification. When you test it in the plnkr I linked, does it act any different than your code?

Comment: @KreepN, yes it looks same to me. I saw your code in plnkr. it is exactly like mine. Another thing it works fine if i try it with "true" comparator for strict comparison as suggested by Betty above.

Comment: @KreepN, i just added my controller code about how i am populating $scope.users. I think somehow "User" keyword is getting confused with user.User object. I am not sure just wondering may be it gives u an idea about problem root cause.

Comment: I went ahead and updated my plnkr to be more inline with your population, but I can't seem to replicate any sort of filtering issue. I mean, it's not exact, but pretty close.

Comment: @ KreepN, i got the problem. I also break your plnkr. The issue is in my user object i have another array i.e. Permissions .. so one of the permission contains User keyword as well thats why it is not working. To check yourself just change ever permission name to User Admin and than check.